# Is there a way to search questions that have been recently asked without getting old but recently modified ones?

Tags: support

The [*Questions*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions) link lists both the questions that has been recently asked, and old questions that have been recently edited.

Is there a way to get only the recently asked questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in chat, there's the "newest" tab that shows the questions sorted by date:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest

Comment: I noticed that `http://english.stackexchange.com/questions` shows a different list of questions basing on which link you followed before; for example, if you before visited `http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active`, then that is the list you get when you successively click on [Questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions).It doesn't show the same list of questions as I thought it should do.